# how can i write the procedure for search using logical operator?

Tags: sql-server-2005

in my application i have to write the procedure for search. so that user can give any combinatin of words like 'ar rehman and slumdog or daneboel ' like this how can i write the procedure for thi. using logical operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the words of the Office helper thing: "It looks like you are trying to create a search engine!..."

If you are trying to create some sort of search then you may well be better off using [SQL Full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) or perhaps [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), which has been ported to many languages.

If you do want to do this in SQL then you will need dynamic SQL, and my **strong** recommendation would be to dynamicly generate the SQL on the client, not inside a stored procedure - and when I say dynamically generate SQL I literally mean generate something like:

```
WHERE (Name = 'rehman' and SomeField = 'slumdog') or Name = 'daneboel'
```